# Why I can't change color on hover of nav tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navigation created using nav tabs.

I wan't to set color on hover, but I can't

I tried this, but not working .

```
.tab2:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.tab3:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <nav class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="tab1"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Name &nbsp &nbsp<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> </a></li>
            <li class="tab1"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>Text Link </a> </li>
            <li class="tab1"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Message </a> </li>
            <li class="tab1"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-oil"></span>10 </a> </li>
            <li class="tab1"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span> &nbsp </a> </li>
            <li class="tab1"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp </a> </li>
            <li class="tab2"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> &nbsp &nbsp KATEGORIJE </a></li>
            <li class="tab2"><a href="#">RADNJE</a></li>
            <li class="tab2"><a href="#">VOZILA</a></li>
            <li class="tab2"><a href="#">NEKRETNINE</a></li>
            <li class="tab2"><a href="#">NAJNOVIJE</a></li>
            <li class="tab2"><a href="#">HITNO</a></li>
            <li class="tab2"><a href="#">USLUGE</a></li>
            <li class="tab2"><a href="#"> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> &nbsp &nbsp OSTALI LINKOVI </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.nav>li>a {
    padding: 10px 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.tab1 {
    background-color:#324255;
    height: 42px;
}

.tab2 {
    background-color:#405072;
    height: 42px;
}
.tab3 {
    background-color: #405072;
    height:42px;

}
.nav-tabs li {
    border-left: 1px solid #52617b;
    border-right: 1px solid #52617b;

}

ul {
    background-color: #405072;
    height:43px;
}


.tab2:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.tab3:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Use .tab1 and not tab1, it's a class so use the appropriate selector. Therefore .tab1:hover{  }

Comment: If you cannot set it like that, inspect the page and use specificity to override the actual background color applied to .tab1 - instead of .tab1 use .row .nav.nav-tabs .tab1:hover{ }

Comment: thank you but not working, because on hover I have border with set color, i want background colro not border color. Look ilustrated http://i.imgur.com/OpPTnps.jpg

Comment: Okay so a couple things I'm noticing.
-Your col-md-10 should be inside your row and not the other way around. -Also it's wise to have a total of 12 columns in a row.
-You don't have a closing </nav> tag. 
-I put your html & css in a fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/otuy1foo/  and it seems to do what you're asking.

Comment: You probably have a grey background color over the green background color. So I don't think you have a border color ;) 
Just try to find the grey background color through your inspect element and take it out and you should probably be fine. I'm saying all this based on the image you provided.

Comment: @Brain I don't know why on jsfiddle works perfectly on my computer not working, i posted full code, and i added now close nav tab
https://jsfiddle.net/zos57rnw/

I don't set grey color, maybe integrated in bootstrap, how to find that O.o

Comment: no worries, I know why it's not working. I'm fixing it for you now and will post it in a few min in the answer. And you can give me the credit for it.

Comment: @Brain Have you solved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75662/discussion-between-brain-and-igor-simic).

Comment: If the answer is correct, I'd appreciate it if you give me the credits. 
Good luck with the coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to be as specific as I can so you understand it all. 
 1. When I pasted your html and css in the fiddle, I forgot to add the link for bootstrap stylesheet in the html as well. Bootstrap uses a CDN as you might know and it allows you to link with their stylesheet without downloading it and actually placing it in your website folders. 
 This is the link I am referring to:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I just added this above all the html in the fiddle.

2. To answer your original question. Bootstraps stylesheet is overwriting your stylesheet.

Your `<li>` is working fine and has a green background. But the `<a>` has a background color of its own which is coming from bootstrap.

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/otuy1foo/3/. And in the css I placed the css code in comments at the bottom.

```
/*This is the css you need to add*/
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    border-color: transparent !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```